# How do I override a RenderElement?

Tags: 8, theming

There is a Drupal 8 RenderElement called HtmlTag, which controls how HtmlTags are rendered. I would like to override this so that I can change its default behaviour.

I could write a class that extends HtmlTag and override what I need, but then how would Drupal core and the theme system know to use my new class?

Alternatively, maybe I should be using `hook_theme_registry_alter()` to tell Drupal 8 to use my new class?

I'm not really sure of the best way of achieving this and there don't seem to be any examples of this being done.

Comment: Why are you trying to override the HTML_tag element?

Comment: Might be to override the default void elements @Eyal

Comment: To convert all script tags to just plain paths for use in a JSON array. This is for use in a javascript based script loader.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`hook_element_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/8) would be one option, not sure it's the best.

The existing class sets 2 pre render callbacks, which you can override in your own class:

```
function MYMODULE_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  $types['html_tag']['#pre_render'] = [
    [\Drupal\mymodule\HtmlTag::class, 'preRenderConditionalComments'],
    [\Drupal\mymodule\HtmlTag::class, 'preRenderHtmlTag'],
  ];
}

...

namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\HtmlTag as CoreHtmlTag;

class HtmlTag extends CoreHtmlTag {

  public function preRenderHtmlTag($element) {
    // ...
  }

  public function preRenderConditionalComments($element) {
    // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: This is interesting. Will this lead to issues if multiple contrib modules do this?

Comment: There will be a race @Kevin, yep - but no more so than hooks in previous versions. It's predictable too, and we still have good 'ol `hook_module_implements_alter` to force an order on the hook implementations if that does happen

Comment: I should add this doesn't feel right for other reasons @Kevin - there's a distinct possibility of violating DRY if the OP wants to, for example, just override the static `$voidElements` var - because the parent class uses `self` rather than `static` to reference it, the whole of `preRenderHtmlTag` would need to be copy-pasted across

Comment: @Clive, is it possible to overwrite the content of `$voidElements`, because it  is only protected not private and then call `$element = parent::preRenderHtmlTag($element);`?

Comment: Unfortunately not @4k4  - if the parent class was referring to it with the `static` keyword it would work, but with it using `self::$voidElements` it'll always refer to the variable in core's HtmlTag, not the extending class

Comment: My idea was not to override, but to **overwrite** the static variable. Can I edit your answer?

Comment: Have you tried it @4k4? To the best of my knowledge that isn't possible, and indeed what late static binding was introduced to solve in php

Comment: Could you confirm you've actually tested the code you edited in @4k4? I'm pretty sure that won't work, just away from my computer so can't try at the moment. Unless you've tested and 100% confirmed it works, id be grateful if you revert the edit until you get a chance to

Comment: Hope that didn't come across rude @4k4, wasn't meant to, I'm just 99% certain that `self` can only ever refer to the actual class you're in, not a relation of it in either direction. Might be wrong though, I don't spend a lot of time in php these days, maybe something changed or I've misunderstood something

Comment: You are right, there is probably no other solution than copy and paste. it was my limited knowledge, I was thinking that the protected static var is kind of a global in parent and child. But in this case it does not work, as you've explained and i didn't unterstand at the beginning because of `self`.

Comment: @Clive: reality is that this classes do not use self:: anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If hook_element_info_alter() doesn't go far enough for you, there's a core issue to add a hook_element_plugin_alter() to directly alter the plugin class for an Element (of which RenderElements are a subset): https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2987208

The core patch is a one-line addition of `$this->alterInfo('element_plugin');` in `ElementInfoManager`, which specifies this new alter hook.

Then in your custom module:

```
function hook_element_plugin_alter(array &$definitions) {
 // Use a custom class for the HtmlTag element.
 $definitions['html_tag']['class'] = '\Drupal\mymodule\RenderElement\MyHtmlTagElement';
}
```